# group the values from different dictionary with same key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries:
`x = [{'a': {'b': 'c'}}, {'a': {'d': 'e'}}]`

I want the output `[{'b': 'c', 'd': 'e'}]` which is grouping of values if the keys are same from different dictionary. In the above example the key is 'a' and I want to get the values from all the keys with 'a'.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: And what piece of information are you missing to complete your attempt to a working solution?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use a loop over the dictionaries and the keys, with [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) and [`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) as helper:

```
out = {}
for d in x:
    for k, v in d.items():
        out.setdefault(k, {}).update(v)
```

Output: `{'a': {'b': 'c', 'd': 'e'}}`

If you're only interested in one key (e.g. "a"):

```
out = {}
for d in x:
    out.update(d.get('a', {}))

# optional
# out = [out]
```

Alternatively:

```
from collections import ChainMap

out = dict(ChainMap(*(d['a'] for d in x if 'a' in d)))
```

Output: `{'b': 'c', 'd': 'e'}`